# Prove that there's a $e_n\in\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ such that $y_n\notin A$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, normed-spaces

I'm reading the book "Calculus on Normed Vector Spaces" and found a detail that I don't understand. The one I didn't understand is the following:

Let $(E,\parallel \cdot \parallel)$ be a normed vector space.

> Suppose that $A\subset E$ is an open and closed subset and that $A\neq$
>   $E$ and $A\neq \emptyset$. Also, set $a\in A$ and $b\in E\setminus A$
>   and let us set $\overline{t}=\sup\{t\in[0,1]:a+s(b-a)\in A,\, 0\leq$
>   $s\leq t\}$. Clearly $\overline{t}\in(0,1)$. Now we set
>   $\overline{x}=a+\overline{t}(b-a)$ and
>   $x_n=a+\left(\overline{t}-\frac{1}{n}\right)(b-a)$ for
>   $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$. The sequence $(x_n)$ lies in $A$ and
>   converges to $\overline{x}$. As $A$ is closed, $\overline{x}$ belongs
>   to $A$. By definition of $\overline t$ there exists a sequence $(y_n)\subset$
>   $E\setminus A$ where $y_n=a+(\overline{t}+e_n)(b-a)$ and
>   $0<e_n<\frac{1}{n}$.

My question is: why $(y_n)\subset E\setminus A$?

I tried to prove that for each $y_n$ there's $e_n\in\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right)$ such that $y_n\notin A$, but I couldn't.

I tried to prove it by absurd:

Let's say that the negation is true, then $\forall\epsilon_n\in\left(0,\frac{1}{n}\right):y_n\in A$. 
$\overline{t}=\sup\{t\in[0,1]:a+s(b-a)\in A,\, 0\leq s\leq t\}$, therefore for a element $t$ of that set we have that $a+s(b-a)\in A$ when $0\leq s\leq t\leq\overline{t}<1$, because $\overline{t}\in(0,1)$. By the Archimedean property of the real number, there's $m\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$ such that $1-\overline{t}>\frac{1}{m}>\epsilon_m\Rightarrow 1>\overline{t}+\epsilon_m>\overline{t}$. Therefore

$0\leq s\leq t\leq \overline{t}<\overline{t}+\epsilon_m<1$

Then I could not think of anything else. Could someone please help me?

**EDIT:** I realized that the problem lies in proving that $\overline{t}\in\{t\in[0,1]:a+s(b-a)\in A,\, 0\leq s\leq t\}$.

**EDIT 2:** If we prove that $[0,\overline{t}]\to A,\, s\mapsto a+s(b-a)$ is a map, then the problem will solved.

Comment: Here is a proof of the fact that $\overline {t} =\{t \in [0,1]:a+s(b-a) \in A$ for $0\leq s \leq t\}$: take a sequence $\{t_j\}$ increasing to $\overline {t}$ such that $a+s(b-a) \in A$ for $0\leq s \leq t_j \}$ for each j. Clearly $a+s(b-a) \in A$ for $0\leq s <t\}$. It remains only to see that $a+t(b-a) \in A \}$ but this follows from the fact that A is closed.

Comment: I know that $a+\overline{t}(b-a)\in A$, but I don't know if $a+s(b-a)\in A$ for all $0\leq s\leq \overline{t}$. Imagine that $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of $A$. Since $A$ is closed we know that $0\in A$ because it's the limit of that sequence. However we can't  conclude that $[0,1]\subset A$. That why I couldn't show that $\nexists t'\in[0,\overline{t}]$ such that $a+t'(b-a)\notin A$. I am imagining that there is some detail in your explanation that I didn't understand. Could you explain it better? Because it might be correct.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy See my **EDIT 2** in the question.

Comment: The fact that $a+s(b-a) \in A$ for $s< \overline {t}$ is already obderved in my proof: choose $\{t_n\}$ increasing to $\overline {t}$ and note that any $s< \overline {t}$ is less than $t_n$ for some n.

Answer (score 1):

The $y_n$ are in $E \setminus A$ by definition of $\bar{t}$. Since $\bar{t}$ is the supremum of the values $t$ for which $a + t(b-a) \in A$, we must have that for all $t > \bar{t}$, $a + t(b-a) \notin A$. So long as the $e_n$ are positive, $\bar{t} + e_n > \bar{t}$.

Comment: The problem is that I couldn't show that $\overline{t}$ is in that set. If $\overline{t}$ isn't there so is possible to have $(y_n)\subset A$.

Comment: On second thought, I believe the author erred in that passage. What do you think?